# Allow Backspace with character set

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am having trouble deleting in my text field. So I have a text field for a person name only allowing letters. But when I hit the delete or backspace it doesn't seem to work. This is what my code looks like.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let set = CharacterSet.letter
    return (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: set) != nil)
}
```

I am not sure why the backspace/delete is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the user taps the backspace, `string` will be the empty string. So `rangeOfCharacter` will be `nil` so your code returns `false` preventing the backspace from working.

Try this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.isEmpty || string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letter) != nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy. I was stuck here for a while looking why It didn't work, Thanks.

Comment: Makes so much sense... works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you tap the backspace check for backspace code and return false if `rangeOfCharacter` for your regular expression is `nil` else return true.

Try this:

```
        let  char = text.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
        }else if text.range(of: kRangeWithoutSpace, options:.regularExpression) == nil {
           return false
        }
```